# Appending to sublists using "anchor" values

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Say I have a set of lists that look like this:

```
list = {{{151.335`, 245.102`}, {1, 1}}, {{41.435`, 245.021`}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}},
        {{131.048`, 243.364`}, {3, 3}, {56, 56}, {76, 23}}, {{164.911`, 244.039`}, 
         {4, 4}}, {{98.1685`, 239.618`}, {5, 5}}, {{196.333`, 239.212`}, {6, 6}}, 
        {{184.767`, 234.228`}, {7, 7}}, {{213.044`, 234.24`}, {8, 8}}, 
        {{26.6316`, 221.423`}, {9, 9}}};

appendList = {{{3, 3}, {"Yellow", "Red"}, {"Blue", "Majesty"}},
              {{76, 23}, {"White", "Avalanche"}}}
```

How can I use the first element in each sublist of `appendList` as an anchor to append the next set of elements in place in `list` generating something like the following?:

```
finalList = {{{151.335`, 245.102`}, {1, 1}}, {{41.435`, 245.021`}, {2, 2}, {3, 3},
              {"Yellow","Red"},{"Blue","Majesty"}}, {{131.048`, 243.364`}, {3, 3},
              {56, 56}, {76, 23},{"White","Avalanche"}}, {{164.911`, 244.039`}, 
              {4, 4}}, {{98.1685`, 239.618`}, {5, 5}}, {{196.333`, 239.212`},{6,6}},
             {{184.767`, 234.228`}, {7, 7}}, {{213.044`, 234.24`}, {8, 8}}, 
             {{26.6316`, 221.423`}, {9, 9}}};
```

After-the-fact question:

This is a brief followup which doesn't quite deserve it's own question - how can we only look at the last element in each sublist of `list` to check to see if it matches the "anchor" value at the first position in `appendList`?

In other words, where `{{{2, 2}, {"Yellow", "Red"}, {"Blue", "Majesty"}}, {{56, 56}, {"White", "Avalanche"}}}` yields a `finalList = list` since {2,2} and {56,56} are not at the ends of the sublists in `list`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is the following:

```
list /. (RuleDelayed[{x__, #[[1]]}, {x}~Join~#] & /@ appendList)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is using `Sequence`

```
list /. (#[[1]] -> Sequence @@ # & /@ appendList)
```

Comment: Ah, the parentheses seem to make it work!

Comment: Do you know a quick fix to address my "after-the-fact question" added to the question body?  It seems simple, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it with a simple one-liner.

Comment: @HStoley I'm already thinking about it. In this case my solution transforms to `list /. ({x___, #[[1]]} :> {x, Sequence @@ #} & /@ appendList)` which is equivalent to tom's solution :)

Comment: Ah, so Tom's solution automatically does this?

Comment: And thanks for thinking about the update.

Comment: @HStoley Yes, check it!

Answer (score 4):

Here is my variation of tom's solution.  (It too handles the "after-the-fact" addition.)
I use `##` ([`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html)) and `@@@` ([`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) at level one)  for more concise code.

```
list /. ({x___, #} :> {x, ##} & @@@ appendList)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Lookup`:**

Create a lookup table:

```
lut = (First@# -> Rest@#) & /@ appendList
```

> {{3, 3} -> {{"Yellow", "Red"}, {"Blue", "Majesty"}}, {76,     23} ->
> {{"White", "Avalanche"}}}

Join every row, with the sequence provided by the lookup, if any:

```
res = Join[#,
    Sequence @@ Lookup[lut, {Last@#}, Nothing]
    ] & /@ list


res == finalList
```

> True

I have benefited greatly from the techniques on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this using `ReplacePart`:

```
f[l_List, al_List] := Module[{parts, pos},
    parts = Extract[
            GroupBy[l,
                Function[
                    Apply[Or,
                        Map[Function[SameQ[Part[#, 1], Part[#, 2]]],
                                
        Transpose[{ConstantArray[Last @ #, Length @ al], al[[All, 1]]}]
                            ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            Key[True]
        ];
    pos = Map[Position[l, #] &, parts];
    ReplacePart[l,
        Thread[
                pos -> Map[MapApply[Sequence, #] &,
                    Transpose[{parts, Part[al, All, 2 ;;]}]
                ]
            ]
    ]
  ]

 f[list, appendList] === finalList

 (*True*)
```